# ESXi USB passthrough not working for Windows 2012R2 guest

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2, usb

- A USB device (Feitian HID dongle) is physically attached to a VMWare ESXi host (5.1.0).
- The USB dongle is configured in passthrough mode for a Windows 2012 R2 (VMWare Level 8) host.
- The Windows host does not "see" it - it doesn't appear in device manager or in the removable devices list.

Same device on same host if configured for a Linux guest comes up in the lsbusb output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have both a USB controller and the device itself added to the virtual machine in order to make the pass-thru option work.

It would be an easier setup though to not use hardware pass-thru. Instead make sure you have the proper USB controller on the virtual machine and VMware tools have been installed. VMware tools will provide the drivers needed for the controller. Once the virtual machine is up and running with these installed then just attach the USB device using the consoles control panel. You should have a listing of available devices to choose from.

Comment: I added the xHCI USB hub and then simply added the device and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect dongle to VM (in VM hardware settings)?

You should also add USB Controller to VM Hardware. Then connect usb device, also check if you have usbarbitrator in ESXi running.